# Timersub and timeradd on AIX

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, linker-errors, aix

I'm fairly new to the AIX platform. Currently porting an application from linux to AIX. 
I know timeradd and timersub aren't supported on AIX which is why I get the following error:

```
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .timeradd
ld 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .timersub
ld 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.
```

Is there a workaround? Or a patch for the definitions?

Comment: You can find the sources in *http://www.sbin.org/doc/unix-faq/programmer/faq_8.html*

Comment: One manual page for FreeBSD 11.0 [`timeradd()`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/3/timeradd/) et al.  They're not difficult to write.  How did you get the code to compile without declarations for the functions in scope?

Comment: @Jonathan, He's using the base ANSI C compiler, which has the default function assumptions (function returning int).

Comment: @cup found the definitions in the link you posted. Will try those and follow up.

Comment: Those definitions were useful. Thanks @cup